# Check if the active cell is in a specific named range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any elegant way to do this? I'd rather not check the row and column coordinates against the coordinates of the named range.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any other way to verify if the active cell is in a specific named range, other than checking the coordinates against the coordinates of the named range.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been doing. I was just hoping that Google had implemented some change since I've last had to do it. It just seems a bit sloppy.